# Angular getting document was not found on this server error when I used ng build --prod

Tags: angular, typescript

When I working in my local there was no problem but When I upload created files from `ng build --prod` to the server after than there is a problem when trying to route via a button in my components. it's giving that error when I click for route [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxtt0.png) `404 The requested document was not found on this server.`
and `{path: 'callcenter/:id', component: CallCenterComponent}` in my app.module.ts  It working in my local  [you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdpgf.png) Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share some of the code, the app routes, the app module ?

Comment: @Kayra if all the routes are giving the same issue and only the root path works, its a server issue, you need to configure the server for single page applications!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { CallCenterComponent } from './call-center/call-center.component';
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'kullanicilar', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'callcenter', component: CallCenterComponent},
    {path: 'callcenter/:id', component: CallCenterComponent},
    {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent},
    {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent}
];
```

in my app.module.ts